# Sanity check SSH public key?

Tags: linux, bash, encryption, ssh, rsa

I have asked users for their public "id_rsa.pub" ssh key, that I then place in "/home/theiraccount/.ssh/authorized_keys", so they can login to the server by SSH.  I'd like to automate this process.

Is there anyway to sanity check the string they give me (programmatically or otherwise)?  I want to verify that sshd can read the text and that it actually looks like a valid public key (and hasn't been corrupted)?

Put another way, what is the format of the `id_rsa.pub` file?  If someone enters it in a field what can I write in the form handler script to verify that it is complete and correct?

Comment: Here's a link to a function written in Python that validates keys: https://github.com/jirutka/ssh-ldap-pubkey/blob/master/bin/ssh-ldap-pubkey#L264 Assuming you're just interested in basic validation, the algorithm is basically: 1. split the contents, first element is `kt` = key type, second element is key string. 2. base 64 decode key string 3. first four bytes are integer `ktl`, corresponding to length of key_type string 4. get chars 4 through 4 + `ktl` of decoded string 5. it should match the key type `kt`.

Answer (score 32):

`ssh-keygen` can be used to calculate the fingerprint of a key file, which will fail if you don't pass it a key:

```
ssh-keygen -l -f id_rsa.pub
```

Another possibility would be [`ssh-vulnkey`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/ssh-vulnkey.1.html), that would have the advantage of checking the keys against the blacklist of known compromised keys at the same time.

Comment: does not work for keys with passwords

Comment: @vidstige A _public_ key protected by a password? Why? The public key shouldn't need to be protected by a password, the private key should, and you wouldn't give that to anybody. What workflow would require sanity checking private keys?

Comment: For me, even with passphrase it worked.