# Check string is an SSH public key

Tags: perl, ssh

I have a string and I want to check it is an SSH public key. I tried this (`$pk` contains a filename not a string in this case):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Crypt::RSA;

my $pk = "$ENV{HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub";
my $public = new Crypt::RSA::Key::Public( Filename => $pk );
```

but I get error like

```
Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 13) line 1
< ... >
Can't bless non-reference value at perl5/lib/perl5/Crypt/RSA/Key/Public.pm line 28.
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336169/sanity-check-ssh-public-key) a "non-Perl" solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $string  = '123';
my $string2 = <<'EOF';
<real public key string>
EOF

for my $pk ( $string, $string2 ) {
    chomp $pk;

    my $file = '/tmp/pk';
    open my $fh, '>', $file;
    print {$fh} $pk;
    close $fh;

    if ( !system("ssh-keygen -l -f $file > /dev/null 2>&1") ) {
        print "[$pk] OK\n";
    } else {
        print "[$pk] NOT OK\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With reference to a previous, but similar answer:

[Is it possible to sign my data using SSH private key in perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342257/is-it-possible-to-sign-my-data-using-ssh-private-key-in-perl/27343929#27343929)

I think you'll have difficulty with `Crypt::RSA` because of the difference in format for the key files.

Comment: Thanks but what is the difference?

Comment: Never mind. I'm being daft. Bear with me, and I'll dig a bit deeper. #

Comment: Yeah, I think there's a different format used for ssh public keys to 'normal'.